# Illustrator scripting: setting bleeds

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, mac, javascript, plugin

Trying to solve this has been an odyssey, thanks in part to Adobe's new community platform breaking old links. Most of what I found is in [this thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/setting-the-bleed-in-ai-via-javascript/m-p/8975095).

So for some stupid and arbitrary reason, document bleeds can't be set via script. They can be set with a [plugin](https://community.adobe.com/space/5510), but thanks for breaking that link, Adobe! I can't find an archived or cached version of that thread anywhere.

The source for a Mac plugin is [here](https://github.com/ten-A/Bleed) but I have no idea how to compile it, and the developer provides no documentation on how to do that. I got as far as downloading the Illustrator SDK and pulling the plugin repository into Xcode 11.3, setting the target to MacOS 10.13 as specified in the SDK documentation, but I can't get it to build, it can't find IllustratorSDKDebug.pch (and neither can I).

I'm lost, and beyond annoyed that something that should be as simple as declaring a four-element array in JS has turned into this. Any help with this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.   I'd suggest you contact Adobe instead if you are upset about their support serivces. There really isn't anything we at GDSE can do about it. Sorry about that. Also help with compiling pluggins or coding in general is off-topic here. Maybe Stack Overflow would be better suited.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Billy! If only we could get Adobe to take suggestions. But you're right, this is more of a SO question.